# Is there a difference between green movement and blue movement?

Tags: endless-space

All ships in Endless Space have a speed (listed in Parsecs / Turn) that varies based on faction, engine modules, random events, and researched technology.

Some of these above grant a modifier that is colored blue, and some of these grant a modifier that is colored green.

What's the difference between these two modifiers?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This makes me want to play some more... Is there not a difference between normal flight and warp speed?

Comment: @Fluttershy no idea.

Comment: I don't know near enough about this game, but I'd wager the blue increases parsecs in normal travel, and green increases warp speed parsecs...

Comment: One of the techs specifies that blue arrows is normal travel, and green arrows is traveling to a friendly/owned star system. Not sure if that applies consistantly though, as I vaguely recall seeing blue arrows for INDIVIDUAL ship speed, and green arrows for overal FLEET speed. I'll have to pay extra attention to my next game and see if there is any consistancy used in the tech descriptions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I *think* the blue type of speed only applies when traveling through the cosmic strings (IE, the predescribed network), whereas the green type applies to movement straight from one system to another without the use of a connecting 'string'.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're right, especially since in-game travel along the strings has blue dots and warp travel has green ones.

Answer (score 0):

It varies in the tech description. For instance, one speed tech grants +2 general movement and is shown in blue, and +6 movement when traveling TO a friendly star system and is shown in green. One tech grants a +8 to non cosmic string movement and is shown in blue.

On the main map, cosmic string movement is shown in blue for further turns movement (and white for this turn movement) and 'off road' movement is shown in green for further turn movements (and white for this turn movement).

Comment: That'd still make me think that Shadur is correct. I.e., +6 when moving *to* a friendly star system, but only when not using cosmic strings.